# What is PackageManager.FEATURE_WEBVIEW for?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

My app uses WebView. As of L-preview, there is a new feature filter introduced:

FEATURE_WEBVIEW. Declares that your app must only be installed on devices that fully implement the android.webkit.* APIs. Example:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.webview" android:required="true" />
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#Manifest

I would like to understand the impact and the reason of this feature filter.

1. Which devices won't implement full android.webkit.* API?
2. If I add this line into my AndroidManifest.xml, I expect my app will still be available for Android 2.3-4.4. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which devices won't implement full android.webkit.* API?

Android Wear, and perhaps others.

> If I add this line into my AndroidManifest.xml, I expect my app will still be available for Android 2.3-4.4. Is that true?

It should be.

Comment: If this is just because of Android Wear, than it seems a bit strange to differentiate things based on just webkit...?

Comment: @LeoK: The goal isn't to distinguish Android Wear from non-Android Wear. The goal is to distinguish Android environments that support `WebView` from Android environments that do not support `WebView`. Android Wear happens to be one that does not support `WebView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for the answer. If we put Android Wear aside, may I assume that vendors are now able to ship Android smartphones and tablets with AOSP WebView instead of Chromium-based WebView? These devices will not support full webkit API, but some portions of it (as it was in Android 4.3, for example). Does that make sense?

Comment: @DimaKornilov: I am not aware that this feature is in reference to what you cite.